# Execute sql script in a different schema

Tags: oracle

How to execute a SQL script(.sql) in a different schema in SQLPLUS. I do have all permissions on the schema.

Answer (score 9):

try:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = different_schema
```

Comment: Getting the below error:

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02248: invalid option for ALTER SESSION

Comment: probably should have mentioned, you need the  ALTER SESSION privilege